# validate an australian phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been attempting to validate an australian phone number using javascript however it has been accepting everything. It needs to be 10 numbers long beginning with 0 accepting spaces:
`02 4345 2334`
and together
`0243452334`.
I think the regex might be wrong or the code itself

```
function PhoneNumberVal(form){
    var phoneFormat= /^0[0-8]{2})\)?[ ]?([0-9]{4})[ ]?([0-9]{4})$/;  
    var phoneLength = document.getElementById('phone').value.length;

    if(phoneFormat.test(phoneLength)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Not a valid phone number");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: tip: Don't bother with spaces. Trim the value after insertion and remove spaces before continuing with matching the desired.

Comment: Try this regex:- `/^0[0-8]\d{8}$/g;`

Comment: `^0[0-8]\)?[ ]?([0-9]{4})[ ]?([0-9]{4})$`

Answer (score 0):

Your  regex is wrong. `^0[0-8]{2})\)?[ ]?([0-9]{4})[ ]?([0-9]{4})$` you failed to put the opening parenthesis and you need to change `[0-8]{2}` to `[0-8]`, since your input contains exactly 10 digits.

```
^(?:\(0[0-8]\)|0[0-8])[ ]?[0-9]{4}[ ]?[0-9]{4}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/27)

Comment: it wont validate the spaces. It appears as though there is more than 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

Regex? Ha! [Now you have two problems.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

**UPDATE:** This version should be final.

Just do this:

```
function IsAustralianTelephoneNumberValid(a_telephone)
{
    a_telephone = a_telephone.replace(/\s/g, ''); // remove all spaces

    // if is empty OR first char is NOT 0 
    if((a_telephone=='')||(a_telephone.charAt(0)!='0'))
    {
        alert("Not a valid phone number");
        return false;
    }

    // lets save the length of that string before we remove digits
    length_with_digits = a_telephone.length;

    // now string has its digits removed
    a_telephone = a_telephone.replace(/0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9/g,'');

    // if is nothing, then there was no other characters in string
    // except digits and spaces AND ALSO if the difference of length before the digits
    // removal and now is 10 then we can be sure we had 10 digits and nothing else,
    // so its valid. Any other case is not valid.
    if((a_telephone=='')&&(length_with_digits-a_telephone.length==10))
    {
        alert('ok');
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Not a valid phone number");
        return false;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7vzL4jm/10/

Comment: it also needs to start with 0

Comment: @programmingHelp oh thats easy. ill fix this give me a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex,

```
/^\D*0(\D*\d){9}\D*$/
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/587g4bwc/)**